# iOS 7.1 simulator on XCode 5.1.1 doesn't launch, shows a black screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios7.1

So it just never launches, even without a project when I just want to start the simulator from XCode, all I get is the phone with a black screen in it, the home button will not even work, the screen remains black forever

However if I just go to hardware -> device -> iOS 6.1 to switch the iOS version to 6.1 instead of 7.1, it will launch the home screen, so it must be an issue with the 7.1 simulator that came with the fresh XCode install (5.1.1) And I got the iOS 6.1 simulator using the XCode downloads.

What I tried doing:

iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings..
Restarting the computer
Deleting everything in /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator

Thanks!

Comment: I also noticed that obliterating XCode and removing anything to do with it then doing a fresh install from the app store is a way to have the iOS 7.1 simulator run, although it's not always an ideal solution